# Load 10 items at once ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, load, adapter

I'm developing an app that has a listview timeline feed, a unique item fills the entire screen, then I'm navigating through the feed, the items only loads when they become visible on the screen, I need load them before them appear on the screen, like load 10 items at once.

My Adapter:

```
    public class FeedRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        public FeedRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<FeedView> arrayList)
                throws Exception {
            this.activity = act;
            this.row = resource;
            this.items = arrayList;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(act);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(row, null);
                // LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                // .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                // view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }                

            if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
                return view;

            objBean = items.get(position);

            //Some stuff here

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // PUBLICAR Auto-generated method stub
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // PUBLICAR Auto-generated method stub
            return items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // PUBLICAR Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

    }
```

EDIT:
I'm already using on scroll to load more items, but the items has images to load, and it only loads when the item appears on the screen, I need that image load before become visible, like a preload. I'm using Picasso lib to load images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be to check if the last item is visible, and if it is then load more items.
In order to check if the last item is in the view, you can use the following function with these method signatures.

```
public abstract void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
```

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html

Here is a tutorial that does exactly what you are looking for http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly

Comment: Sorry, I think you didn't understand what I mean. I'm already using on scroll to load more items, but the items has images to load, and it only loads when the item appears on the screen, I need that image load before become visible, like a preload. I'm using Picasso lib to load images.